# How to keep ssh connected when I connect to a VPN tunnel?

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn

I'm facing this issue: I have a cloud vm that I can only access through ssh, this vm is meant to be used as a openvpn connection tester. Each time opevnvpn establishes a connection I lost my ssh session and cannot connect back until I reboot the vm from my cloud provider interface.

The only way is possible to regain ssh now is to kill openvpn after sleeping for 15 seconds:

`sleep 15 && pkill -SIGTERM openvpn`

some notes:

- preferably I don't want to touch the .ovpn files, but I could if it's needed
- I'm running through `tmux`; so when I quit ssh client the vpn tunnel stays alive

question:

- Is there a way I can keep ssh alive without having to kill openvpn?

Comment: The underlying problem is about routing, not really ssh. Most certainly openvpn changes routes including the one for the ssh connection. That's all I can say with the information (not much) provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to add `--ifconfig-noexec`

Quoting from [man page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage):

> Don't actually execute ifconfig/netsh commands, instead pass --ifconfig parameters to scripts using environmental variables.

```
openvpn --ifconfig-noexec --config /path/to/client-config.ovpn
```

Comment: To future people that find this answer.  This is the answer mostly because this system is being used to test OpenVPN functionality. If the vpn was actually being used, you would need to fix the routing properly.